# MySQL compare two datetimes with date_add

Tags: mysql, datetime, compare, schedule, dateadd

It's about schedule. User select 1 datetime and I need to compare it with DB, if I don't have something else in that time and +-2 hours (rounded)..

Both datetime are saved in SQL "DATETIME" format (yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss)

Conditions are: user-DATETIME can't be more or less then 1 HOUR and 59 MINUTES (7199 SECONDS) as DB-DATETIME

I try following:

```
SELECT event FROM schedule
WHERE '2014-08-02 12:00:00' > DATE_ADD(event, INTERVAL -7199 SECOND) OR
WHERE '2014-08-02 12:00:00' < DATE_ADD(event, INTERVAL +7199 SECOND)
```

that fixed datetime in this example is for checking.. the real datetime is in string $_COOKIE["userdt"]. Pretty sure I'm close, but can't accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to write your query is:

```
SELECT event
FROM schedule
WHERE '2014-08-02 12:00:00' > DATE_ADD(event, INTERVAL -7199 SECOND) AND
      '2014-08-02 12:00:00' < DATE_ADD(event, INTERVAL +7199 SECOND)
```

This changes the `or` to an `and` and removes the second `where`.

However, I think a better way to write the query is:

```
SELECT event
FROM schedule
WHERE event > DATE_ADD('2014-08-02 12:00:00', INTERVAL -2 hour) and
      event < DATE_ADD('2014-08-02 12:00:00', INTERVAL +2 hour);
```

There are several reasons for these changes.  First, `interval 2 hour` is much easier to understand than `interval 7199 second`.  It clarifies what the query is doing.  The `>` and `<` basically implement the same logic (okay, there is one second of difference on either end, but my guess is that is not important).

Second, try to get in the habit of doing transformations on the "constants" rather than "columns" in the `where` clause, when you easily can.  This allows MySQL to use an index on `event` for the query.  When `event` is first processed by a function, MySQL will not (generally) use an index on the column.

Comment: yes, I noticed that second WHERE as soon as I sent that question, but thanks for advices, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Other than mispelling the sql sentece, it's the user input which you should compare instead of the field in the table.  This should return any event field between 2014-08-02 10:00:00 and 2014-08-02 14:00:00

```
SELECT event FROM schedule
 WHERE  event > DATE_ADD('2014-08-02 12:00:00', INTERVAL -7199 SECOND) 
 AND event < DATE_ADD('2014-08-02 12:00:00', INTERVAL +7199 SECOND)
```

**UPDATE**

I missed the *OR* which will then return anything before 2014-08-02 14:00:00 and after 2014-08-02 10:00:00 so in fact will return everything. (Thanks to Gordon who noted :P)